# Excel/XLSX library SheetJS is undefined after import

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to create and export an Excel spreadsheet.

This is my code:

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx'; 

const downloadExcel = () => {
    console.log(XLSX);
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(excelExport);
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'kelvin');
    //buffer
    let buf = XLSX.write(workbook, { booktype: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    //binary string
    XLSX.write(workbook, { booktype: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
    //download
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'kelvin.xlsx');
  };
```

When trying to use this function, I get the following error:
`Kelvin.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')`.  Additionally, when outputting the XLSX variable to the console, it says that it is undefined.

How am I supposed to import the contents of the 'xlsx' package?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error.  In order to resolve it,

I changed the import line from: `import XLSX from 'xlsx';`

to this: `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

based on this comment from the repo maintainer: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/393#issuecomment-1300947901

and the project documentation: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/frameworks#usage

The fundamental issue is that, in SheetJS's transition from CJS to ESM modules, the way that bundlers would expose the exports changed resulting in needing to change the import method as outlined above.

Comment: it worked on "xlsx": "^0.18.5"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a Vuejs project.

My workaround was to go back to version 0.18.0 of xlsx (latest version right now is 0.18.5)

```
"xlsx": "^0.18.0"
```